# Is it possible to dynamically change global stylesheets in Angular 2?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular

Is it possible to dynamically change global stylesheets?

EDIT: The purpose is to allow the user to pick the styles he prefers.

In Angular 1, I was able to wrap a controller around the head tag and use bindings in there.

Example below (simplified code):

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app" ng-controller="AppController">
<head>
    <title>Title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" ng-href="styles/{{current}}"/>
</head>
...
```

AppController

```
app.controller('AppController', ['$scope', function ($scope ) {
    $scope.current = dynamicValue;
}]);
```

Is this possible in Angular 2?

Comment: Have you tried it? What happened?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish by dynamically changing the link tag? There's probably a different way to achieve the same functionality. :)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I ended up using the DOCUMENT token as Igor mentioned [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/8509).

From there, I was able to swap the href for the style.

HTML:

```
<head>
   <link id="theme" rel="stylesheet" href="red.css">
</head>
```

TS:

```
import { Component, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Component({})
export class MyClass {
    constructor (@Inject(DOCUMENT) private document) { }

    ngOnInit() {
      this.document.getElementById('theme').setAttribute('href', 'blue.css');
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the path of blue.css in your repo (where did you place it)?

Comment: style is added to the head but styles are not applying

Comment: Worked well for me, 

  ngOnInit() {

    setTimeout(function(this){
      this.document.getElementById('theme').setAttribute('href', 'assets/style-2.css')
    }, 3000);
  }

I added a timeout so you could see the styles being applied

Answer (score 3):

No, you can't use any bindings outside Angular applications. Angular applications can only be at or inside `<body>`. Therefore no way to make this work.

You might have a look at the implementation of the [`Title` service](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/platform-browser/index/Title-class.html) for how to access elements in `<head>` or use just plain JS/TS to modify it imperatively.

Answer (score 1):

try this: in your root component template include a variabled stylesheet link.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app',
  template: `
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/{{ current }}">
    ...`
})
export class AppComponent {
    current = 'site1.css';
}
```