# Angular 2 Conditionally apply stylesheet

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, angular, styles

I have an angular 2 - bootstrap 3 application that requires the color scheme of a page to be set dynamically based on user input/database value.

For this purpose, I have a set of color schemes defined in separate stylesheets. I am using the same class names in all the stylesheets, but the colors are different. Now, I need to use the appropriate stylesheet at runtime. How do I achieve this?

Thanks,
Shilpa

/* Edited to add - **Answer** */
The answer from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37730801/is-it-possible-to-dynamically-change-global-stylesheets-in-angular-2) worked for me

Comment: Have you considered the ngClass directive?

Comment: Is this what you're looking for?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37730801/is-it-possible-to-dynamically-change-global-stylesheets-in-angular-2

Comment: Are you looking to change the app global stylesheet or just a single component?

Comment: @R. Richards. Yes, I have considered that, but there are too many elements across too many components. I was hoping there is an easier mechanism.

Comment: @Jim, the link seems to answer my question. I will check it out. Thanks very much :)