# Click to change component style

Tags: angular, click, components, styles

I would like to add a new style to my component if i click a button.
i would like to switchings it.

Deafult is  my.componenet.scss

New version is my2.componenet.scss

its my component loading i would change styleurls when i click a function

```
@Component({
  selector: 'mycomponent',
  templateUrl: './mycomponent.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./mycomponent.component.scss'],
})
```

there is my function

```
  public LoadDefaultStyle(){
    //  loading it styleUrls: ['./my.componenet.scss'], after rendering page
  }

  public LoadNewStyle(){
    //  loading it styleUrls: ['./my2.componenet.scss'], after rendering page
  }
```

Can you give me some instruction?

Comment: Maybe you could use this answer? It seems to be very similar to your problem. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37730801/is-it-possible-to-dynamically-change-global-stylesheets-in-angular-2

Comment: Hi, I don't think this is the correct way to achieve your requirement. Please refer Angular theming document ==> https://material.angular.io/guide/theming-your-components

Comment: Its worked for me  mangeshbhuskute

Answer (score 0):

Please write the style in different two classes and toggle the class on click.

```
 <div class="test_class" (click)="changeColor()"  
    [ngClass]="status ? 'success' : 'danger'">                
     Some content
</div>

    let status: boolean = false;
changeColor(){
    this.status = !this.status;       
}

.success{
  color: green;
}
.danger{
  color: red;
}
```