# Ionic add sheet style dynamically

Tags: css, angular, ionic4

Why can I not add stylehseet dynamically between head tag of app ionic?

Thanks very much.

I'm using

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" [href]="sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(cssUrl)">
```

but it's only working in `app.component.html` and not working in `index.html`

Thanks

Comment: Stylesheets should not be dynamically replaced. If your css is small enough I recommend you combining all in one like `.style1 { /* all your css /* } .style2 { /* all other css /* }` and then change class for the container.

Comment: Also, I recommend you adding more details. I guess, this is Angular ionic app, and your index.html is the main html file. You generally don't do such things in that html file in angular.

Comment: @Oybek i have 3 sheet style (1500 lines for sheet). Yes,  is Angular ionic app, and index.html is the main html file. This is for 3 option of theme.
I managed to add the style sheet in the component with [href]= , but it doesn't work in general (it adds it in the body) and the styles don't work

Comment: Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37730801/is-it-possible-to-dynamically-change-global-stylesheets-in-angular-2) question. Also, the `DOCUMENT` object seems to be moved to a different project. For that matter refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56826692/export-document-was-not-found-in-angular-platform-browser) question.